# Could somebody share a thematic link or post a text of an interview with project manager? (For programmers)

Tags: resource-request, english

Could somebody share a thematic link or post the text of an interview with a project manager?

The context is job interviews for programmers.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Could you please edit your question so it is clear how it is relevant to language learning?

Comment: I want to learn a grammar, related to interviewing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Are you looking for help in preparing for a job interview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many resources about job interview for learners of English on YouTube. Below is a selection. (This is just the tip of the iceberg. When you watch a few of these videos, YouTube will also suggest similar videos.)

**American English**:

- [Learn English - A Successful Job Interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkPTJwSWnJ8) (60 minutes, for people who need basic skills for interviews).
- Learn English with Ronnie: [Job Interview Skills - Questions and Answers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqeghm8Uut8) (11 minutes).
- Rachel's English: [Job Interviews in America -- Tips for Interviewing in English](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrqHrGoMJdTTAUF6xjlAtW27NYxtYzNu7) (playlist with 5 videos, each between 7 and 17 minutes long).
- Twominute English: [Job Interviews in English Language - English Phrases for Job Interview - Job Interview Conversations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwLqqWKvSao) (4 minutes).
- [Job Interview with Game Developer Turbine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7AENaKu2pA) (20 minutes).
- [Job Seeker Interview with Game-Maker Turbine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtQIhkuMN9k) (14 minutes).
- CTE Skills.com: [Job Interview....good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SieNfciN274) (human resources position, 4 minutes).

I have not found any examples of programmer job interviews in **British English**, but there is plenty of other materials for British English on YouTube:

- BBC Learning English: [Business Language to Go: Job Interviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMYc2BwWh4o) (11 minutes; this is about job interviews for learners of English; it does not contain an example).
- Benjamin's English Classes (engVid): [Top words for your JOB INTERVIEW & RESUME](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wAf4EX3-BI) (14 minutes).
- Jade Joddle (on EngVid): [What to say at your job interview (all my BEST phrases and tips)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMYc2BwWh4o) (23 minutes; about job interviews, for learners of English; does not contain an example).
- Jade Joddle & Benjamin: [Job Interviews - The 'Winner' and the 'Victim'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbJrttm7Lo0) (8 minutes; contains examples of a good and a bad interview, but unrelated to programming).
- Jade Joddle: [How to stop your mind going blank in interviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2hN8wkMdfY) (8 minutes).

Other videos:

- Learn English with Let's Talk: [Interview Skills Training](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5A7D7B0557C7F9BD) (playlist with 6 videos, each between 3 and 9 minutes long
- Funny video in Indian English: Mahmudul Hasan: [job interview for programmer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtKqGa66CTM) (6 minutes).

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you!